# One Foreign Key with 2 References Table

Tags: mysql, sql

is it possible to have a foreign key with two reference tables?

here's the script and we're having a problem inserting into this table

```
CREATE TABLE Class(
    idNumber varchar(30) not null,
    day varchar(10) not null,
    time varchar(20) not null,
    foreign key(idNumber) REFERENCES ThesisMember(idNumber),
    foreign key(idNumber) REFERENCES Faculty(idNumber),
    PRIMARY KEY(idNumber,day,time)
);

CONSTRAINT `class_ibfk_1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`idNumber`) REFERENCES `thesismember` (`idNumber`))
```

SQL Statement:

```
INSERT INTO `thesis`.`class`
    (`idNumber`, `day`, `time`) VALUES ('9990', 'F', '0940-1110')
```

the Faculty table has the "9990" idNumber.

Comment: it is not possible. you cannot reference one column with two tables.

Comment: What if *both* tables have a row with `9990`? Is this a reference to both tables? Or to just one? Which one? How would *we* decide, on looking at it? How, then, would MySQL decide?

Comment: Works4me: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/aecbb

Comment: isn't it much easier to find out whether it's possible or not just by trying it out?

Comment: Working fine [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/864ac/4)

Comment: @DreamEater how? only one table(Faculty or ThesisMember) can have "9990".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The FK constraint requires that every instance of the field 'idNumber' occur in ALL referenced tables. You state that only one of the referenced tables has the value to be inserted, so of course an error occurs on the INSERT attempt.

Comment: No; it is possible PROVIDED that the idNumber is always going to occur in both tables. You should have a master table owning the PK idNumber, with ThesisMember and FacultyMember being detail tables off of it. An additional idType field would identify whether an idOwner was a ThesisMember or a FacutlyMember.