# One Foreign key linked with two tables

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys

I have a database with three tables:

```
Tab1
IdTab1
DataTab1

Tab2
IdTab2
DataTab2

Tab3
Id
RifTab (contains 1 or 2)
IdRifTab (contanins the rif id of one of the two tables)
```

Assuming that IdTab1 and IdTab2 are primary keys, is it possible to create a foreign key for IdRifTab with the two tables depending on value of RifTab?

I know that probably I'm asking for impossible but I'm a self-taught and I learned that asking is the better way for learning.

I want to precise that I looked for a solution to the problem and I found this: [One Foreign Key with 2 References Table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15241822/one-foreign-key-with-2-references-table) 
but my case is different: I need to distinguish the ids of a table from those of the other.

Any suggest is appreciated

Thank you for your time.

Comment: continuing to search I found this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20692529/attempting-to-avoid-polymorphic-associations and I think is a bit over my current knowledge. I'll try to understand criteria to work with polimorphic associations. The prolem is that my real db has 5 tables with ids to link and not two like in the example...
Thanks to everybody

Answer (score 0):

this is a similar question and you might want to take a look.
[Conditional Foreign Key to multiple tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3965683/conditional-foreign-key-to-multiple-tables)

Even that I myself don't think that this is a nice elegant solution. Maybe you can review the database schema and come up with a better solution :).